# How to remove sensitive information from error email in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a Django site that takes in sensitive information.  I use https/SSL, so I'm pretty good on that stuff.  However, I had an unhandled error today that occurred on a POST of some information.  Upon reviewing the error report that was emailed to me, I realized (much to my horror) that the sensitive information had gone across the wire (in the email) unencrypted.

I've done a few searches on Google, but am not really finding much information on this topic.  It seems like I could probably implement my how exception handler and plug it into

```
from django.core.handlers.base import BaseHandler
```

But, all I really want to do is to strip out the information from the request.POST on certain views.  Seems like maybe I could maybe create a decorator for views that will contained posted information that I don't want included in the emails.

What's the best way to handle this?

EDIT: Adding version information.

I'm currently using Django 1.3.1 with a PostgreSQL 9.1 database (not that it probably matters here)

Comment: It side-steps your question, but personally, I'd recommend using Sentry (https://github.com/dcramer/sentry), and not email at all.

Comment: @Chris Pratt...  Well, you are correct that it doesn't really answer the question, but then again, you didn't submit it as an answer (only a comment). :)  I appreciate it.  I'd never heard of this before and it looks very cool.  I'm currently using Loggly, but this might be an alternative replacement for that.  I will have to do a bit more research and understand the advantages of each.

Comment: FWIW, Sentry is made and used by the same people behind Disqus. Since they eat their own dogfood, as the saying goes, you can be reasonably sure that Sentry will remain supported and will get frequent updates and bugfixes. And, best of all it's free. Gaining back $149 per month will buy a lot of extra servers ;).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django might have you already covered in this, it provides hooks for filtering sensitive information:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/error-reporting/#filtering-error-reports

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Very cool...  I did not know this.  So, up vote for that!  But, unfortunately, I'm using 1.3.1 (I've added this information to the original question).  Any ideas for 1.3.1?

Answer (score 0):

Django 1.4 has pluggable support for just this kind of filtering: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/error-reporting/#filtering-error-reports

Comment: But be careful: the filtering is far from comprehensive or foolproof. In particular, if you have any secrets/keys/passwords in the unix environment passed to the web server they will NOT be filtered and will be included in the error report.